# UK Income Tax on rental income from property

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, rental-property, gbp-british-pound

My wife and I have a buy-to-let property held jointly. My understanding is that the profit from rental of this property should be split 50/50 for the purposes of income tax. If the profit per person is less than £2500 does this mean it is not liable to income tax?

Comment: Where did you get the £2500 figure from? The government website on this (https://www.gov.uk/renting-out-a-property/paying-tax) says to contact HMRC if your income is less than that amount, but doesn't say it's exempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it isn't exempt and I would like to know where you got this information from.

> If the rental profit (gross income less allowable expenses) is less than £2,500 a year, and the gross rental income (before deduction of expenses) is less than £10,000 a year, you can ask HMRC to collect any tax due through your PAYE code. You would need to send the tax office a statement of your rental income and expenses each year. HMRC would then change your PAYE tax code to collect the additional tax from your employment or pension.

[Source](http://taxaid.org.uk/guides/information/rental-income-savings-income-and-pensioner-issues/property-owner/how-property-rental-income-is-taxed)

Comment: Source: my wife. *Commencing smug mode*

Comment: This is a moderately common misunderstanding. Below £2500 in untaxed income (in any form) HMRC generally won't require you to do full on self-assessment, but they still require you to disclose and they absolutely will want any tax due.